# Getting parameters in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a url like this
somesite.com/home/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}/{param4}

How I will define Controller's action to get values of these params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `Request("ParameterName")` to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
public ActionResult ActionName(object param1, object param2, object param3, object param4)
```

You can change *object* to match the parameter's type.